# How to add data from one data frame to another by row, only when the value in the first column in both dataframes is equal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. For each row in dataframe2, I want to see if dataframe1 already has a row with the same value in column 'name'. If it does, I want to add the data from the row in dataframe2 to corresponding row in dataframe 1. The value in column 'name' should not be added across. Steve should not be copied across and bob should have no new data added.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'Ben', 'goals': 1, 'minutes': 90},
                    {'name': 'Bob', 'goals': 1, 'minutes': 64},
                    {'name': 'Kevin', 'goals': 1, 'minutes': 90}])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'Ben', 'goals': 1, 'minutes': 88},
                    {'name': 'Kevin', 'goals': 1, 'minutes': 3},
                    {'name': 'Steve', 'goals': 1, 'minutes': 13}])
```

The final output should be:

| name | goals | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ben | 2 | 178 |
| Bob | 1 | 64 |
| Kevin | 2 | 93 |

This is what I have tried

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if df2.isin([row['name']]).any().any():
        position = int(df2[df2['name'] == str(row['name'])].index.values)
        df1.iloc[index, 1:] = df1.iloc[index, 1:] + df2.iloc[position, 1:]
```

Comment: can you provide  your desired output in text table?

Comment: @STOWE Merge the dataframes using `pd.merge()` and then sum the columns. I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Concatenate `df1` + `df2` minus the rows with names that aren't in df1;
2. Group by `name`;
3. Sum the values in each group;
4. Reset the index.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.loc[df2["name"].isin(df1["name"])]]).groupby("name").sum().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
    name  goals  minutes
0    Ben      2      178
1    Bob      1       64
2  Kevin      2       93
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

If there are no duplicate values in the 'name' column, try using this code.

```
out = (df1
       .set_index('name')
       .add(df2.set_index('name'), fill_value=0).loc[df1['name']]
       .astype('int')
       .reset_index()
)
```

out

```
    name  goals  minutes
0    Ben      2      178
1    Bob      1       64
2  Kevin      2       93
```